# Using Azure Metrics Advisor with workout data

Tags: azure, azure-metrics-advisor

So I saw Azure Metrics advisor in Microsoft Ignite this year and decided to try to using it against some workout data that I had from Endomondo.
I uploaded 4 years of running data (only about 400 records) into an Azure SQL instance.
[image]
Then, I ingested that as a data feed into an Azure Metrics Advisor instance.

Literally, I'm just taking metrics advisor for a spin, so now I want to use this historical data for new running data.
I'd like when I upload a new workout I can run it against this data and have anomalies in either my distance or duration detected.

Does that use case make sense